# How to have edit work like adding within Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a create method that works fine. Within this create, an image is saved to a separate table. Within my Person class I have a collection of files

```
public virtual ICollection<File> Files { get; set; }
```

When I use the create method, I have this line that works fine.

```
db.Persons.Add(person);
```

This will create the person record and add the file as well. I can then view the file later.

If however, I want to change the file and I use edit, I can update all other information except for the image file. This is what I'm using to update within the edit.

```
db.Entry(person).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

Why is this? I can recreate the record but I have other relations hanging off the person table and it seems more difficult to add these back. Am I missing something fundamental, have I provided enough info?

Thanks all

Comment: Are you getting an error?

Comment: No error, and the file seems to be populated when debugging.  I really think it's just this one line that has to do with how entityframework is called.